# Simple past vs. past subjunctive in 'if' clauses

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditionals

I understand the usage of the past subjunctive but I'm confused whether I should use it in these kind of cases, because it sounds so stilted when I say it:

> 'If I [had/were to have] money, I'd go to the shops'
>
> 'If we really [wanted/were to want] to, we could go'

As far as I know we should use the second option in both these cases because it is a past subjunctive+conditional clause, but they just sound wrong. I feel this is similar to:

> If we [fell/were to fall] down the hill, we'd have a hard time getting back up'

In this case it feels like the 2nd one is right, and doesn't sounds stilted at all. Are both options acceptable?

Comment: Hmm. I don't know why you think the subjunctive *should* be used in the first two. They seem like simple if/then sentences. The third example is a correct use of the subjunctive. Plenty of people would not use the subjunctive, though, in informal speech.

Comment: @medica what is the difference between the first set of examples, and the second one then? They seem similar to me

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as Modern English has a past subjunctive (it differs from the past in precisely one word in the entire language: "were" vs. "was"), both "had" and "were to have" are subjunctive, and both are appropriate to a counterfactual conditional. The difference is that "were to have" is more tentative than "had" - not necessarily more unlikely: it's about how the speaker is expressing the condition, rather than any objective difference in the condition.

Answer (score -1):

First, "were" is **not** subjunctive; there is no past subjunctive in English, despite what you may have read or been told. Subjunctive is not a mood; it is a type of clause construction headed by a plain form verb, as in *It is vital that I be kept informed*.

The "**were**", as instanced solely by 1/3 sg forms of the verb "be" and typically used in conditionals, is better called 'irrealis' mood. In your examples, the "were" in "were to have/want/fall" is irrealis mood, but "had/wanted/fell" are just modal preterites, not irrealis.

It all boils down to a choice of the formal irrealis "were" or the less-formal modal preterites.

Comment: -1: This "answer" dogmatically repeats the totally useless assertion that *"were"* is not subjunctive, and does not actually answer the question. In Shakespeare's English, *if I were a woman* was one of a broad range of uses of the subjunctive, *"If this be false"* to *"command that their 
wives be as free as heart can wish or tongue can tell"*, which were undisputably one grammatical construction. Now, t only two uses of the subjunctive are left. They look completely different, and some grammarians decided that calling one of these the *irrealis* would be less confusing. They were wrong.

Comment: Excuse me? I answered the question by clearly stating that 'formality' was the deciding factor in that the OP has a choice of formal "were" (whatever you may choose to call it) or the less-formal modal preterite alternatives. As regards the irrealis vs past subjunctive argument, here's a link to a useful post on Language Log by Stanford's Arnold Zwicky on the subject. If you just want a 'quick fix' just read GKP's bit in para 3: [link](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001192.html). Read and learn!

Comment: The question, as I understood it, is: why does *"if we really were to want to go ..."* and *"if I were to have money"* sound absolutely terrible and *"if we were to fall down the hill ..."* sound fine? This doesn't answer that. And most of your answer consists of a  rant about how *were to* is not really a subjunctive, which is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @BillJ You around?